Regression Result - Interpretation Interaction Term
I am confused about how to interpret the interaction term in the regression result.
Here is the result:

WorkatHome is the binary variable and is 1 when people work at home; otherwise 0 (work at the office)
SingleFamily is also the binary variable and 1 when people live in a single-family; otherwise 0 (live in multi-family)

I did my interpretation as "people who work at home tend to have more job satisfaction when they live in a single-family than those who work at the office".
I got a comment that the interpretation is wrong. The comment said that the interpretation should be a comparison with the people who live in a multi-family instead.
Please help me understand what is the correct interpretation.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Your question is very similar to this question, with your WorkatHome and SingleFamily replaced by female and white. Each coefficient is a difference from lower-level reference conditions (here, work at office and multifamily). The individual coefficients are differences when only 1 variable is changed; the interaction is the extra difference from what you would predict from the individual coefficients when both are changed. Please read that other question and edit yours to specify what's still unclear.

I'm assuming that the values on the right of the image are p values and that this is a linear regression in the form:
$\log(\text{satisfaction})=\beta_0+\beta_1 \text{WorkAtHome}+\beta_2 \text{SingleFamily}+\beta_3 \text{InteractionTerm} +...+\epsilon$
What this allows you to do is to analyze a linear regression that might change based on another binary variable. So in this scenario, you are making a regression line for 4 groups of people:

Those who work at home but don't live in a single family
Those who don't work at home but live in a single family
Those who don't work at home and don't live in a single family
Those who work at home and live in a single family

So what the p values tell us is that there is a stronger correlation between Log(Job Satisfaction) and Single Family and Work at the home than all of the other groups. However, since these are p values we can't really make a conclusion about the magnitude of these predictors, we can only say that the correlation between working at home & single family and log(Satisfaction) is statistically significant. To figure out how effective or how strong the correlation is you would need to look at different values or tests. Hope this helps.
You can read more here: Minitab Explanation
Which pretty much says : The coefficient for a term represents the change in the mean response associated with a change in that term, while the other terms in the model are held constant. The sign of the coefficient indicates the direction of the relationship between the term and the response. The size of the coefficient is usually a good way to assess the practical significance of the effect that a term has on the response variable. However, the size of the coefficient does not indicate whether a term is statistically significant because the calculations for significance also consider the variation in the response data. To determine statistical significance, examine the p-value for the term.

Thank you very much, It helps me a lot.
